# Internal server error on connections API retrieving current-share field

Tags: api, linkedin-api, connection

I've been having an issue querying linkedin information through the connections API.

Of all my connections there's this one contact that seems to be kind of buggy.

So I'm basically querying the following API:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(current-share)?count=1&format=json&modified-since=0&start=35
```

returns internal service error:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Internal service error",
  "requestId": "WSKG1J703S",
  "status": 500,
  "timestamp": 1446053949746
}
```

So far my conclusions on this issue are:

- Only happens for this connection (I'm able to query the remaining connections)
- Only happens when the fields include current-share, I've tried other fields and all of them work for this connection
- Current share from the connection seems to be an updated profile photo, I have asked a friend to change his and it still worked for him.

I've looked at similar questions but most solutions point to reducing the number of connections being returned and I'm currently retrieving just one, as seen above (I have tried to return a batch of 100, 250 and 500 all have the same issue when the batch processes that one connection).

Anyone knows what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedIn's Connections API is no longer openly available.  If you have access to it and are experiencing issues, you should get in contact with your Partner Engineering representative at LinkedIn, rather than inquiring in a public forum.